# Desplegar array entero usando puntero doble , puntero a puntero

Tags: c

Deseo que imprima 100 200 300
Mi codigo es el siguiente pero me da error cuando lo ejecuto, pero no al Compilar
el puntero doble**p2 logra imprimir el primer elemento notas[0] pero al intentar
imprimir el siguiente da error , ventana de DEVc++ el programa dejo de funcionar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*Desplegar array entero usando puntero doble*/

int main() 
{
    int notas[3]={100,200,300};
    int *p1=notas;        /* Puntero a array*/
    int **p2=&p1;         /*puntero doble */
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%d ",**p2);
        p2++; 
    }

    //ME SALE ERROR AL EJECUTAR en DEV C++pero no al compilar

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué dice el error? En lo posible, incluye el texto del error en tu pregunta como texto y no como imagen

Comment: Solo sale una ventana de aviso
Proyecto1.exe dejó de funcionar Windows buscara una solución Uso dev c 5.11

Comment: No tengo un compilador a mano para probarlo, pero el problema es que incrementas el puntero doble, y eso hace que se salga de direcciones (el incremento hace que apunte a algún sitio desconocido). Lo que tienes que hacer en el bucle es incrementar el CONTENIDO del puntero doble, que es una direccion. Debería ser algo como `*p2++` o `*p2+=sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás haciendo se conoce como…

#### Aritmética de punteros.

El lenguaje C es de [tipado fuerte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte), lo que significa que todos los datos tienen un tipo específico que no puede cambiar *pero* si puede ser convertido. En el caso de los punteros, **siempre** serán puntero **a algo** además de tipo puntero.

Así que, un puntero a entero (`int *`) y un puntero a caracter (`char *`) son ambos punteros, pero son punteros **a algo** diferente y por tanto de tipo distinto. Este concepto es vital para la aritmética de punteros.

Se puede aplicar sobre un puntero operaciones aritméticas como la suma (`+`) y la resta (`-`)<sup>1</sup>, esto sumará al valor del puntero (que es la dirección de memoria en que se encuentra el dato apuntado) el tamaño del tipo apuntado, por ejemplo:

```
char *pc = NULL;
int *pi = NULL;

pc = pc + 1;
pi = pi + 1;
```

[En el código anterior](https://wandbox.org/permlink/L9HS5mQnARFpjFQA), `pc` y `pi` apuntan inicialmente a la dirección `0x0` (dirección nula) y al finalizar apuntan a la dirección `0x1` y `0x4` respectivamente pese a que ambos se les ha sumado el mismo valor; esto se debe a que `char` (tipo al que apunta `pc`) ocupa un byte de memoria mientras que `int` (tipo al que apunta `pi`) ocupa cuatro<sup>2</sup>.

#### Tu problema.

Estás aplicando aritmética de punteros sobre los punteros erróneos. Cuando avanzas `p2` (el puntero a puntero) estás dirigiéndote al siguiente puntero a puntero, no al siguiente puntero a entero:

```
[notas] ---> [ 100 | 200 | 300 ]
   ^
   |
[ p1 ]   ??? ---> ???
   ^      ^
   |      |
[ p2 ] [ p2++ ]
```

No te sale error al compilar porque la operación que haces es conceptualmente válida, pero el programa es erróneo en su funcionamiento.

Al avanzar `p2` una posición, es posible que estés apuntando a la posición que contiene `200` o a la que contiene `300`<sup>2</sup>, lo cuál se interpreta como puntero a des-referenciar (`**p2`) y al tratarse de una dirección de memoria que no corresponde con tu programa: provoca un fallo en tiempo de ejecución. Lo que en realidad querías hacer es:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("%d ",**p2);
    (*p2)++; 
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Consecuentemente también el `++`incremento, `--`decremento, `+=`autosuma y `-=`autoresta;

<sup>2</sup>Estos valores pueden cambiar según [la arquitectura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquitectura_de_computadoras).

Answer (score 2):

Cuando defines el puntero doble
`p2** = &p1`

Estás asignando al puntero p2 la dirección de memoria de p1.

En el bucle,incrementas p2, lo cual va a hacer que apunte a otra dirección de memoria diferente.
Si quieres recorrer el array, debes desreferenciar p2 e incrementar el puntero al que apunta, que en este caso sería p1.

Si en el código que propones cambias:

```
p2++;
```

Por:

```
(*p2)++;
```

Incrementarás el puntero de primer nivel y podrás recorrer el array.